# Unable to click on dynamically changing div by using selenium with Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, dynamic

When I enter the www.reddit.com , and paste query to Search field, send enter and go to the first valid link with subreddit, I do have sorting options - by default it is set to BEST, but I'd like to change it to TOP. I'm using Java with BDD and POP. Here's my test class code :

`public void top_most_top_tile_will_be_printed_on_screen() throws Throwable {
redditDetailsPage.changeSorting();
}`

my Page code:

```
@FindBy (id = "CommentSort--SortPicker")
private WebElement sortingOption;
@FindBy (xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/a[2]/button")
private WebElement topOption;

public RedditDetailsPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public RedditDetailsPage changeSorting(){
    sortingOption.click();
    topOption.click();
    return this;
}
```

and I believe the problem is with the topOption xpath. I tried to locate it by parent div class, or parent a class name, but I always  got :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[3]/a[2]/button
```

I treid using ExpectedConitions, but it looks like my code is not able to see that it is there - once i Click sortingOption.click() this div is injected :
[image: Div that appears after clicking]

I'd like to also add, that if I do this action manually, then this xpath is valid, and elements are being highlighted. I don't know what else I kind do to sort this list.

Do you know how can I click on Sorting options and select TOP from the list using Selenium ?

---

I don't know how it's possible, but i have compared div gathered from manual testing, and xpath to this element was :
`/html/body/div[3]/a[2]/button`
however when I did the same from the debug ( when the browser from selenium was opened), then it pointed to :
`/html/body/div[4]/a[2]/button`

So actually problem was with xpath, but TBH, i don't know why. Can some try it on their machines pleases ?

Comment: xpaths usually start with a double-slash, so try "//html/body/div[3]/a[2]/button'

Comment: Can you show the html code of the button you're trying to click on?

Comment: Timothy T.     `<a class="s1fauk9w-0 jnqAtA" tabindex="-1" href="/r/Games/comments/apyf2z/activisionblizzard_begins_massive_layoffs/?sort=top"><button class="s1n9jir3-2 dlCVOt b1zwxr-0 hxpTao" role="menuitem"><span class="s1n9jir3-1 gAPvOd">top</span></button></a>`

Comment: racraman:      I tried double slash at the begining, but still `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //html/body/div[3]/a[2]/button
`

Answer (score 1):

From my recommendation, you might use **Chropath** which is an extension for Chrome browser. Chropath will try to find suitable xpath then try to use it

See more detail and download at: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en

If you cannot perform click then try with JS, see as below.

You may use JS to perform click action. [Here is method for C# but it is almost the same as Java].

```
 public static void scrollElementToClick(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor ex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    ex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

Another things that element cannot be click might come from element that represent in page,but not ready to click [clickable]. So you may try to use **wait** that is provided to wait for element before click an action

If you cannot do it, please try to use this to verify when you want to do any action to this element. (This is code is used for C#, but I think you may have the idea):

```
 public static bool existsElement(IWebDriver _driver,By by,int waitBySecond)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0,waitBySecond));



        try
        {

          // wait[wait.until] for element or search element [driver.FindElement]            
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException e)
        {
            // Timeout that set for finding element        
            return false;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
         {   
           // there is no element in this page
           return false;
         }
        catch(Exception e)
       {  return false;
       }
        return true;
    }
```

Q: Do you know how can I click on Sorting options and select TOP from the list using Selenium ?

A: Here is some select from option that you may apply with it

```
         SelectElement changeOwnerMethodSelectedUser = new 
         SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Name("selectedUser")));
                       // then select one choice from options by text appearance
                        changeOwnerMethodSelectedUser.SelectByText("Choice1");
                      // or you might choose by index like this [ Recommended - If you want to select choice by Top option]
                          changeOwnerMethodSelectedUser.SelectByIndex(3);
```

Note: All of this source code are used for C#. Please change syntax to Java before you test it.

Comment: Right now, I used Kathlon Recorder extension [See at : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid ] that is tool for automated test just clicking the element then it will automatically turn into code. You also choose which type of unit test that you want to generate [eg. Junit, Nunit]

Comment: I do have chropath, this xpath was generated by it. I Belive the problem is with the functionality of this hidden div, because entire code is being added when i Click on sortingOption webelement.

I will try to use your notes and will let you know.

Comment: @Bartek Can you try with Katalon Recorder . It will help you to create script

Comment: Another thing you might try is to see when your path has changed because you already set @FindBy (xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/a[2]/button") . but it was changed to   other one

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors below to change sort options to top:

```
@FindBy (id = "search-results-sort")
private WebElement sortingOption;

//@FindBy (xpath = "//a[.='Top']/button")
@FindBy (css = "a[href*='sort=top']")
private WebElement topOption;

public RedditDetailsPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public RedditDetailsPage changeSorting(){
    sortingOption.click();
    topOption.click();
    return this;
}
```